# How to properly escape HTML editor content corretly?

Tags: php, html, xss, wysiwyg, htmlpurifier

So I am using TinyMCE editor and have handled getting the content in the text area by using `htmlspecialchars()` which works fine, but I'm a little confused on the other side of using an WYSIWYG editor... The content output part.

I am using HTML Purifier to output the content, but from what I understand I've just been doing for example:

```
$purifierConfig = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifierConfig->set('HTML.Allowed', 'p');
$Purifier = new HTMLPurifier($purifierConfig);
$input = $Purifier->purify($input);
```

I've only tested with the p tags, but does this mean I am going to have to go through everything TinyMCE uses and add it in as what is allowed? Or is there a better way of tackling this problem with safe output of an WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: For what it's worth, the _default_ whitelist that HTML Purifier uses is quite safe. You can skip setting "HTML.Allowed" unless you want to be stricter than the default. :) (I don't know if this classes as an answer - it's slightly orthogonal to your question, but I figured you might want to know anyway.)

Comment: Yeah I just used the HTML.Allowed so that all of the features of TinyMCE will display when the content is output later on. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to set all allowed tags you want, separated by a comma. You can also specify what attributes are allowed by enclosing them with brackets:

```
$purifierConfig = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifierConfig->set('HTML.Allowed', 'p,a[href],b,i,strong,em');
$Purifier = new HTMLPurifier($purifierConfig);
$input = $Purifier->purify($input);
```

I guess for a better understanding, the [printDefinition](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/smoketests/printDefinition.php) can help.